# How do you install xcb on Macos

Tags: macos, installation, xcb

Currently I am creating a little game and now I need to use xcb, Ive tried using brew but that has not worked. Any solutions?

Comment: What **brew** command did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://noknow.info/it/os/install_libxcb_from_source#sec2-1

Installing version 1.13

```
$ wget https://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/libxcb-1.13.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz libxcb-1.13.tar.gz
$ cd libxcb-1.13
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libxcb/1_13
$ make
$ make install
```